# On page refresh, my select option dropdown value is getting selected to default, how to stop it?

Tags: javascript, java, html, oracle-adf

On page refresh, my select option drop-down value is getting selected to default. I want to set it to the previously selected value. On page refresh it should not reset. How i can achieve it in html, java, js.

Comment: Which language answer do you want? JS or Java?

Comment: I think you should be using the [oracle-adf](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle-adf/info) tag instead of adf

Comment: Your state is lost when you refresh the page. If you want it to remain to the previous value, you have to store it somewhere (database, localstorage, etc.)

Comment: My project structure is like as below: My project is on Oracle ADF, and we have prepared the dropdown in a HTML file and stored it on webcenter content server, then draged the html file as content representer on the adf page. Now if any error ocure on the page the page is getting refreshed, so my drop down value also getting refreshed. I dont want the dropdown value to be refreshed.

Comment: How you are setting the value to dropdown? you need to set again that the same way.

Comment: My dropdown structure is simple, i am just using select option html format and on selection of any value i am calling a JS function, and from there i will get the value in java code and my functionality flow will continue. The dropdown is just used for show only purpose but now because of page refresh the value is getting defaulted, so bug raised.

Comment: ok so you need to persist that selected value to the server at some point, via postback or ajax request, and then have some code on the server to retrieve that value and restore the selected option (or leave as default if there's no previous selection), when the page is next loaded.

Comment: Post the relevant code and be more specific in asking. Otherwise, the question will end up deleted.

Comment: Changed ADF tag to Oracle-ADF

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quiet tricky and you don't really explain it accurately in your original question.

Since you are using Content Presenter, that means this code resides in WebCenter content and Oracle ADF itself cannot control its behaviour, as it is just loading the content!